# XPATH filtering with namespace

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a SOAP response and I parse it into XML

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ListUser>
<user username="Alex" active="false"/>
<user username="Bridget" active="true"/>
</ListUser>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Currently I am using a XPATH `//*[name()='user[active=\"true\"]']` to get all the `user` that is `active = true` , but some how the XPATH is returning 0.

May I know which part of the XPATH is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
//user[@active="true"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer `//*[name()='user'][@active='true']`

Comment: The `name()` function should only be used for exposition and should never be used for testing of any kind.